# Add a row in a slickgrid without unique id which will get only after saving that row?

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

In my grid, created with slick grid I am trying to create grid row
.It is possible to get a unique ID only after saving these row data to the back-end database. How can I handle this situation? Without unique id, the cell data is not retained there when I move to next cell

Answer (score 0):

I would do this method:

1. Create a temporary unique_id for the new row data.
2. Post the row data to back-end database and return the id generated on callback.
3. Update the row data with the returned id that was generated.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative and probably faster (in terms of saving a network round trip) solution is that you generate a [GUID/UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) on client side. To back off generating GUID with example JavaScript code, check out this great SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript).

Quote about the collision probability when generating GUID:

> For example, with 3.26x1015 version 4 [RFC4122](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) UUIDs you have a 1-in-a-million chance of collision.

And the quoted code you can generate a GUID with:

```
'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
    return v.toString(16);
});
```

results in:

"3bce4931-6c75-41ab-afe0-2ec108a30860"

So the actual steps of execution I propose are:

1. Generate your cell data
2. Generate the GUID

Voila, you have your unique ID and can move the next cell, row, etc.